# How do I enable SSH from raspbpi cli?

Tags: raspbian

Please I only need a very short answer: How do I enable the SSH server from cli? I have monitor and keyboard connected ;-)

Thanks a lot!
/Soren

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo raspi-config` It is enabled in `Interfacing Options`